# Strategy pattern - How to inject strategies - NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, strategy-pattern

I am developing a solution to implements several providers in a SmsService. I need a way to inject the strategy class from my Context. The problem is the selection depends on an external property. When I try to deploy this code I get

**`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type`**

Here I show you my code:

**Provider Interface**

```
public interface SmsProvider {

    public Integer send(String user, String password,List<Sms> list);

}
```

**Context class**

```
@Component
public class ContextProvider {

private @Inject
    MessageDAO messageDAO;

private @Inject
    SmsProvider strategy;

public Integer send(String user,String password) {

        List<Sms> list = extractSmsList();

        return strategy.send(user,password, list);
}
public void setStrategy(SmsProvider strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
```

**Strategy A**

```
@Component("provider1")
public class Provider1 implements SmsProvider {

private @Inject
    MessageDAO messageDAO;

public Integer send(String user, String password, List<Sms> list) {

Status serviceErrorStatus = messageDAO.find(Status.class, 400);
...
}
```

**Strategy B**

```
@Component("provider2")
public class Provider2 implements SmsProvider{

private @Inject
    MessageDAO messageDAO;

@Override
    public Integer send(String user, String password, List<Sms> list) {
        Status serviceErrorStatus = messageDAO.find(Status.class, 400);
...
}
```

**Using the strategy.**
In this class I get the property and choose the strategy in a switch clause.

```
    @Component
    public class SmsServiceImpl implements SmsService{

        @Value("${net.mycompany.sms.service.smsProvider}")
        private int smsProvider;
        private @Inject
        MessageDAO messageDAO;
        private @Inject 
        ContextProvider context;
    ....
        public Integer send(String user,String password) {

        LOG.debug("Sms provider property setted at: '{}'",smsProvider);
        switch (smsProvider) {
        case 1:
            context.setStrategy(new Provider1());
            return context.send(user, password);
        case 2: 
            context.setStrategy(new Provider2());
            return context.send(user, password);
        }
}
```

I have also try to delete the *@Component* in the strategies classes and *@Inject* in the declaration of smsProvider in Context class and I get a NullPointerException in Dao class and I really need this daos. 
I am using **Spring 3.2.16-RELEASE** and Java 7.0.15
Please a help. Any pointers would be helpful
Thanks in advance

EDIT 
I add the stacktrace in tomcat 6 server:

```
14:58:48.044 - mycompany_myCompanyFramework_Init[ERROR] - [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsBC': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.service.MessageService net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.bc.SmsBCImpl.smsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.SmsServiceImpl.context; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider.strategy; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at net.mycompany.mycompanyframework.component.web.spring.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:37) [mycompanyFramework-web-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) [catalina.jar:6.0.39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.39]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.service.MessageService net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.bc.SmsBCImpl.smsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.SmsServiceImpl.context; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider.strategy; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.SmsServiceImpl.context; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider.strategy; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.SmsServiceImpl.context; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider.strategy; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider.strategy; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.impl.ContextProvider.strategy; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.mycompany.mc.messaging.sms.service.SmsProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of the FactoryBean interface provided by Spring and encapsulate the creation of SmsProvider in proper place.
As you are using annotation configuration then based on your class definitions, the FactoryBean configuration would look like this:

**First**: we encapsulate the selection of the strategy based on the injected external property:

```
@Component
public class SmsProviderFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<SmsProvider>{

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Value("${net.mycompany.sms.service.smsProvider}")
    private int smsProvider;

    @Override
    public SmsProvider getObject() throws Exception {
        SmsProvider smsProvider = null;

        switch (smsProvider) {
            case 1:
                smsProvider = (SmsProvider) applicationContext.getBean("provider1");
            case 2:
                smsProvider = (SmsProvider) applicationContext.getBean("provider2");
        }

        return smsProvider;
    }
}
```

**Second:** Define the configuration bean which getSmsProvder() method will be used when the 'smsProvider' bean would be injected into other beans:

```
@Component
public class Configuration {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean(name = "smsProvider")
    public SmsProvider getSmsProvider() throws Exception {
        return applicationContext.getBean(SmsProviderFactoryBean.class)
                .getObject();
    }
}
```

**Thirdly**: Add @Qualifer when you are injecting the 'smsProvider' (this may not be necessary depending on which spring version you are using):

```
@Component
public class ContextProvider {

@Inject
@Qualifier("smsProvider")
private SmsProvider strategy;
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring profiles for this.
Annotate each implementation with a profile :

```
@Component("provider1")
@Profile("provider1")
public class Provider1 implements SmsProvider {...}

@Component("provider2")
@Profile("provider2")
public class Provider2 implements SmsProvider {...}
```

When you start the application, activate one of the profiles. With spring boot you can do this by setting the property 'spring.profiles.active' on the commandline or in a properties file, for example

```
spring.profiles.active=profile1
```

- you can name the profiles however you like, I used the same name as the component only for simplicity
- annotating the component class with @Profile only works if you are using ComponentScan, if you use Java config, you need to annotate the @Bean method
- You can find more about profiles with spring-boot in the [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)
- You can use profiles also without spring-boot, see this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/)

Comment: Hi @Stefan Isele - prefabware.com. Thanks for you reply. It didn't work. Raise `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` again, it's like Spring ignore this. I have tried to add application.properties in several path as spring doc says and nothing works. I have edited my question with spring version. Should be work with this version?

Comment: How do you instantiate the beans (class Provider1 and Provider 2) ?
Do you use xml, ComponentScan or Java Configuration ?
Also please post the exact exception you get with the stacktrace...

Comment: We are using ComponentScan. src/main/resources/spring -> business.xml      **<context:component-scan base-package="net.mycompany.mc" />**. I have posted the stacktrace

Comment: The stacktrace shows, that **no** bean of that type was found all. This may happen because you did not successfully activate any of the both profiles when you started the application. 
How did you try to activate the profile ?
Do you use spring-boot ?